# Mutually recursive fields in Knockout.js

Tags: knockout.js

I want to solve the following problem in knockout.js: I have three inputs; `price`, `quantity` and `total`, where I want to set

```
 total = price * quantity
```

when I update `price` or `quantity`, but I also want to set

```
 price = total / quantity
```

if I update `total`.

I originally did this with a computed observable, however this only almost worked, but I have a problem with rounding. E.g. if I do

```
quantity(3)
total(100)
```

I want `price` set to 33.33, with only two decimals, while `total` should still be set to 100, so the identity `total = price * quantity` doesn't quite hold.

In the computed observable approach I took, `total` would be set to 99.99 in this case. *This is what makes this situation different from the fullname/firstname/lastname example in the docs*.

Essentially the `price`/`total` fields are mutually recursive. I can't find a good approach to this problem other than manually subscribing, but this feels very unidiomatic, and means I have to manually deal with a bunch of subscriptions etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've done something similar by making "real value" ko.observables  (i.e. quantity, price, and total), tracking focus events on the form fields, and using ko.computed() to re-compute(but not if the current field is selected) and format the values for the form.

That one sentence description sounds complicated, but it's not that complicated code-wise.

JavaScript:

```
var Model = function () {
    var self = this;

    self.quantity = ko.observable(0);
    self.price = ko.observable(0);
    self.price.selected = ko.observable(false);
    self.total = ko.observable(0);
    self.total.selected = ko.observable(false);

    self.formattedPrice = ko.computed({
        read: function () {
            if (!self.price.selected()) {
                 var total = self.total() || 0;
                 var quantity = self.quantity() || 0;
                 var value = total / quantity;
                 self.price(isNaN(value) ? 0 : value);
            }
            return '$' + self.price().toFixed(2);
        },
        write: function (value) {
            value = parseFloat(value.replace(/[^\.\d]/g, ""));
            self.price(isNaN(value) ? 0 : value);
        }
    });

    self.formattedTotal = ko.computed({
        read: function () {
            if (!self.total.selected()) {
                var quantity = self.quantity() || 0;
                var price = self.price() || 0;
                var value = quantity * price;
                self.total(isNaN(value) ? 0 : value);
            }
            return '$' + self.total().toFixed(2);
        }, 
        write: function (value) {
            value = parseFloat(value.replace(/[^\.\d]/g, ""));
            self.total(isNaN(value) ? 0 : value);
        }
    });
};

ko.applyBindings(new Model());
```

In the HTML you'd bind price and total like this :

`<input data-bind="value: formattedPrice, hasfocus: price.selected" />`

`<input data-bind="value: formattedTotal, hasfocus: total.selected" />`

Code at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/djnattyp/djkZp/17/) if you want to see a working example.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer. Just FYI, here's the solution I currently have, might stick to it unless it gives me problems.

```
    var self = this;
    this.price = ko.observable().extend({numeric: 2});
    this.quantity = ko.observable(1).extend({ numeric: 2 });
    this.total = ko.observable(1).extend({ numeric: 2 });

    var unsub_total = this.total.subscribe(function (total) {
        if (self.quantity() != 0)
            self.price(total / self.quantity())
    });

    // setting quantity will update both price and total
    var unsub_qty = this.quantity.subscribe(function (qty) {
        self.total(self.price() * qty);
    });

    var unsub_price = this.price.subscribe(function (price) {
        self.total(price * self.quantity());
    });

    this.unsub = function() { unsub_total(); unsub_price(); unsub_qty(); };
```